# discord_slash: How to actually add a slash command/ why isn't mine working?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I tried to add a slash command 'verify' to the / menu with discord_slash. It appears there and everything seems right.. Until I try to use the command. It should print the slash_ctx (just for test reasons) and send back 'ok', but instead it returns in discord 'Interaction Failed'.

## Current Code

Creating the bot:

```
slashcomms = commands.Bot(command_prefix='_', intents=intents)
```

Creating the slash variable used to add the slash command:

```
slash = discord_slash.SlashCommand(slashcomms, sync_commands=True)
```

Adding 'verify' as slash command with the function:

```
@slash.slash(name="verify", description="Hiermit verifiziert ihr euch", guild_ids=[493472231691780117])
async def verify(ctx: discord_slash.SlashContext):
    print(ctx)
    await ctx.send("Ok")
```

Comment: This also happens to me, sometimes the interaction failed happens eventhough the command actually worked, I think it might be a problem in the discord py slash library.
Also, the Interaction Failed is a quite recent new feature of Slash Commands, so make sure to update the Discord Py Slash API and check again

Comment: I don't know how, but I somehow already fixed it. Now I got the new problem that I can't respond to the sent command, so it will just cancel everything and send 'Unknown message' as error

Comment: Could you show the full traceback ?

Comment: Already found the "fault"; The slash.slash (or maybe the on_message) somehow doesn't like it if you do something with the message from on_message. Now the question is how to check in the on_message function if the sent message is a command  or a normal message?

Comment: I'm not sure if on_message is triggered when using Slash Commands, but you should simply check if `/` is the first letter of the message? I'm not sure I usually don't use on_message

Comment: Oh right, that COULD work, except the /command is an extra class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slash Commands are an extra "class" but you can recognize them as commands as they got no message content and you can put that in the `on_message` function to let the function ignore the command and after all that no more error occurees.