# How to add slash commands with @client.event on_message discord-py-slash (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add slash commands to my existing bot.
Currently Im using

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some stuff   


@slash.slash(name="test",
             description="This is just a test command, nothing more.")
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Hello World!")
```

But when I go to discord, and I type / and the command. I get
`Invalid interaction application command`

I also tried this: [discord_slash: How to actually add a slash command/ why isn't mine working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842743/discord-slash-how-to-actually-add-a-slash-command-why-isnt-mine-working).
But I didnt understand how to ignore the /slash command in `on_message` function.


**Edit**
I tried printing the message.content in `on_message`, but i didnt get any.There are no errors or exceptions in terminal, when I try to execute it. I only get the error in discord.
[This is the only error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfCKb.png)

Thx in advance.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first see `print(message)` in `on_message` to see what you get. maybe you have to only check if `message.startswith('/')` or `message[0] == '/'`

Comment: i used your code to create minimal working code and it works correctly - I can't reproduce your problem. Better show (in question) minimal working code with your problem - so we could simply copy and run it. And add full error message in question (not in comment) - maybe you have different problem then you think.

Comment: @furas I edited the question. Pls check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

I was actually changing a lot of things, but I accidentally thought it was something to do with sync commands, turns out that it wasn't.
The actual reason it doesn't work, it needs an hour to register for global slash command, but if u add guild_ids param to slash decorator it changes to guild_slash_command. It works instantly(less than 1min). I also added sync_command, it applies changes to the slash commands when added or deleted.

##### Edited code

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

guilds_ids = [guild(server) ids]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some stuff   


@slash.slash(name="test",
             description="This is just a test command, nothing more.", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Hello World!")
```

#### Original

After some trail and error, I found out that by removing sync_commands in the slash obj declaration. It worked

This is the whole code..

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
slash = SlashCommand(client)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do some stuff   


@slash.slash(name="test",
             description="This is just a test command, nothing more.")
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too but my command was registered already if that is the case and you edit the command it will take some minutes to refresh in the server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29918553)